# Transforma data using mutate and ncol?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a script that allows me to transform my data. At the moment I have two different scripts depending on the two ways I usually get the data; either in presence/absence form or with the abundance class written next to each case.

Script 1:

```
mutate(data, abundance= case_when(data[,2]== 1 ~ 1, 
                                  data[,3]==1 ~ 2,
                                  data[,4]==1 ~ 3,
                                  data[,5]==1 ~ 3,
                                  data[,6]==1 ~ 4,
                                  data[,7]==1 ~ 4,
                                  data[,8]==1 ~ 4,
                                  data[,9]== 1 ~ 4,
                                  data[,10]==1 ~ 5,
                                  data[,11]==1 ~ 5,
                                  data[,12]==1 ~ 5,
                                  data[,13]==1 ~ 5,
                                  data[,14]==1 ~ 5,
                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Script 2:

```
mutate(data, abundance= case_when(data[,2]=="< 1" ~ 2,
                                  data[,2]=="1 - <5%" ~ 3,
                                  data[,2]=="5 - <10%" ~ 3,
                                  data[,2]=="10 - <20%" ~ 4,
                                  data[,2]=="20 - <30%" ~ 4,
                                  data[,2]=="30 - <40%" ~ 4,
                                  data[,2]=="40 - <50%" ~ 4,
                                  data[,2]=="50 - <60%" ~ 5,
                                  data[,2]=="60 - <70%" ~ 5,
                                  data[,2]=="70 - <80%" ~ 5,
                                  data[,2]=="80 - <90%" ~ 5,
                                  data[,2]=="90 - 100%" ~ 5,
                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_)))
```

Therefore, my data have either two columns or fourteen. I have been thinking about how I could make r distinguish between these two possibilities, and although this option works, the results are not as expected since it adds the value of 1 to all cases.

```
mutate(data, abundance= ifelse(ncol(data)>2, case_when(data[,2]== 1 ~ 1, data[,3]==1 ~ 2,
                                                                                data[,4]==1 ~ 3,
                                                                                data[,5]==1 ~ 3,
                                                                                data[,6]==1 ~ 4,
                                                                                data[,7]==1 ~ 4,
                                                                                data[,8]==1 ~ 4,
                                                                                data[,9]== 1 ~ 4,
                                                                                data[,10]==1 ~ 5,
                                                                                data[,11]==1 ~ 5,
                                                                                data[,12]==1 ~ 5,
                                                                                data[,13]==1 ~ 5,
                                                                                data[,14]==1 ~ 5,
                                                                                TRUE ~ NA_real_), case_when(data[,2]=="< 0,1" ~ 1,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="< 1" ~ 2,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="1 - <5%" ~ 3,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="5 - <10%" ~ 3,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="10 - <20%" ~ 4,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="20 - <30%" ~ 4,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="30 - <40%" ~ 4,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="40 - <50%" ~ 4,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="50 - <60%" ~ 5,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="60 - <70%" ~ 5,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="70 - <80%" ~ 5,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="80 - <90%" ~ 5,
                                                                                                            data[,2]=="90 - 100%" ~ 5,
                                                                                                            TRUE ~ NA_real_)))
```

I hope you can understand me and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is in the `ifelse`. The condition has to be of the same length as the data. A naive solution is to replicate the condition to the length of the data `ifelse(rep(ncol(data) > 2, nrow(data)), ..., ...)`

Below is the solution with some dummy data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

# dummy data
a <- data.frame(V1 = round(runif(10)*10), V2= round(runif(10)*10))
b <- cbind(a,a)
colnames(b) <- paste0("V", 1:4)

# test of "case_when" for each input data format
mutate(b, abundance = case_when(b[,1] == 1 ~ 1,
                                b[,2] == 1 ~ 2,
                                TRUE ~ NA_real_))

#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 abundance
#> 1   3 10  3 10        NA
#> 2   8  5  8  5        NA
#> 3   4  7  4  7        NA
#> 4   9  6  9  6        NA
#> 5   9  1  9  1         2
#> 6   0  9  0  9        NA
#> 7   5  2  5  2        NA
#> 8   9  0  9  0        NA
#> 9   6  3  6  3        NA
#> 10  5 10  5 10        NA

mutate(a, abundance = case_when(a[,2] == 1 ~ 1,
                                a[,2] == 2 ~ 2))
#>    V1 V2 abundance
#> 1   3 10        NA
#> 2   8  5        NA
#> 3   4  7        NA
#> 4   9  6        NA
#> 5   9  1         1
#> 6   0  9        NA
#> 7   5  2         2
#> 8   9  0        NA
#> 9   6  3        NA
#> 10  5 10        NA

# Solution
data <- a
mutate(data, abundance = ifelse(rep(ncol(data) > 2, nrow(data)),
                    case_when(data[,1] == 1 ~ 1,
                              data[,2] == 1 ~ 2,
                              TRUE ~ NA_real_),
                    case_when(data[,2] == 1 ~ 1,
                              data[,2] == 2 ~ 2)))
#>    V1 V2 abundance
#> 1   3 10        NA
#> 2   8  5        NA
#> 3   4  7        NA
#> 4   9  6        NA
#> 5   9  1         1
#> 6   0  9        NA
#> 7   5  2         2
#> 8   9  0        NA
#> 9   6  3        NA
#> 10  5 10        NA

data <- b
mutate(data, abundance = ifelse(rep(ncol(data) > 2, nrow(data)),
                                case_when(data[,1] == 1 ~ 1,
                                          data[,2] == 1 ~ 2,
                                          TRUE ~ NA_real_),
                                case_when(data[,2] == 1 ~ 1,
                                          data[,2] == 2 ~ 2)))
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 abundance
#> 1   3 10  3 10        NA
#> 2   8  5  8  5        NA
#> 3   4  7  4  7        NA
#> 4   9  6  9  6        NA
#> 5   9  1  9  1         2
#> 6   0  9  0  9        NA
#> 7   5  2  5  2        NA
#> 8   9  0  9  0        NA
#> 9   6  3  6  3        NA
#> 10  5 10  5 10        NA
```